# lapism SearchView: How to handle click on back press?

Tags: android, searchview, android-library

I'm using the [lapism `SearchView`](https://github.com/lapism/SearchBar-SearchView) . When I click on Android back arrow or on the lapism `SearchView` back arrow, it hides the keyboard and looses the focus only during 1 second: just after, it re-has focus and the keyboard is  re-opened. Thus it's an infinite loop (if the user re-clicks on the arrow).

I already wrote this on my fragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AppCompatActivity app_compat_activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    app_compat_activity.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayoutHomeFragment).requestFocus();
}
```

It allows me to make the layout have the focus instead of the lapism `SearchView` when the fragment starts.